# Magento: How do I create multiple products each with different custom options?

Tags: magento

I am setting up a new store and this time I want multiple products. Each of those products should have its own custom options and some options might be valid for all of the products. An important point is that the custom options should also depend on each other. I am looking for a flexible way to achieve that.

As an example, I will have cars (Chevrolet, GMC, Ford, ...) and motor-bikes (Honda, Yamaha, ...). There will be much more, its just an example. Whats the best way to start this requirement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html) (not free).